# How to draw SVG element on a plane with THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a copy of an existing svg element in a THREE.js scene. I use [this example](https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132) to convert the svg to image, then I create a plane with texture based on the image and add it to a scene. However, the plane is black. If I use a solid color instead of a texture it's rendered correctly, so something's wrong with my texture.

```
        var legend = document.querySelector("svg.ViewLegend");
        var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(legend);

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 512;
        canvas.height = 64;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData));

        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: texture,
            });
            material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            //If I use the material below, it works correctly
            //var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xCC0000});
            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(512, 64, 1, 1);
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            scene.add(mesh);
        };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to do:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = svgSize.width;
canvas.height = svgSize.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))) );

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  texture.needsUpdate = true;

  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
  material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
};
```

Created fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lg911vs/4/

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Well, it's tricky indeed. Your fiddle is absolutely working when I put my svg instead of yours, but only in Chrome. I'm using FF, and it's essential that it works there as well. Could you please have a look at your updated fiddle in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/7h5hbpww/

Comment: I continued investigation removing gradually parts of my svg to find which node causing failure of a renderer. It turned out that the problem was in my svg node. It doesn't have `width` and `height` attributes specified. If I set them, everything works. Thanks, it would take much more time from me without your help!

Comment: @gaitat Doesn't work if svg has image URLs. Anybody has any workaround for this scenario?